# A unexpected bug which i cant see the line causing it

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have this javascript code and when you type in encrypt("this has no use yet", "B16-4131-8731") it should log the result of 8/7+3*1
But it says unexpected end of input

```js
function encrypt(prompt, MathId) {
  // Prompt to base10
  var convertedPrompt = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < prompt.length; i++) {
    var asciiCode = prompt.charCodeAt(i);
    convertedPrompt += asciiCode;
  }

  // Cut Prompt every 4 letters
  var resultPrompt = "";
  var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  for (var i = 0; i < convertedPrompt.length; i += 4) {
    var part = convertedPrompt.substr(i, 4);
    var letter = letters.charAt(i / 4);
    resultPrompt += part + " (" + letter + ") ";
  }

  var parts = MathId.split("-");
  let mainBase = parts[0];
  let MathOrder = parts[1];
  let ExtraGate = parts[2];

  var conversionTable = {
    "4": "/",
    "3": "*",
    "2": "-",
    "1": "+"
  };

  var convertedMathOrder = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < MathOrder.length; i++) {
    var digit = MathOrder[i];
    var operator = conversionTable[digit];

    if (operator) {
      convertedMathOrder += operator;
    }
  }

  var finalResult = "";
  for (var j = 0; j < MathOrder.length; j++) {
    var digitB = ExtraGate[j];
    finalResult += digitB + convertedMathOrder[j];
  }

  var finalOutput = eval(finalResult);

  return finalOutput;
}

console.log(encrypt("this has no use yet", "B16-4131-8731"));
```

I really cant find the line causing the error

Comment: Step 1. Don't use `eval`. Step 2. if you're going to use `eval` *figure out what you're evaluating*.  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: Looks like `finalResult` has a stray trailing `+`...

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: @VLAZ Step 3. Don't use ```eval```

Comment: this error comes from this line `var finalOutput = eval(finalResult)`, wich is try todo this calculation: `eval('8/7+3*1+')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to mprove your code...

```js
console.log('->', encrypt("this has no use yet", "B16-4131-8731"));

function encrypt(prompt, MathId)
  {
  const
    alphas          = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  , convertedPrompt = [...prompt].map(c=>c.charCodeAt(0).toString(10)).join('') // Prompt to base10
  , resultPrompt    = (convertedPrompt.match(/.{1,4}/g) ?? []).reduce((s,n,i)=> s + `${n} (${alphas[i]}) `,'')
  , [ mainBase, MathOrder, ExtraGate ] = MathId.split("-")
  , ops = 
     { '1': (a,b) => a + b
     , '2': (a,b) => a - b
     , '3': (a,b) => a * b
     , '4': (a,b) => a / b
     };
  let finalOutput = NaN
    , operator    = ''
    ;
  [...MathOrder].forEach( (op,i) =>
    {    
    finalOutput = isNaN(finalOutput) ? Number(ExtraGate[i]) : ops[operator]( finalOutput, Number(ExtraGate[i]));
    operator    = op;
    });
  return finalOutput;
  }
```